# crystal reports: connect tables to convert numeric value to a string value

Tags: crystal-reports

Working with Crystal Reports in Visual Studio and I cannot pull up the correct values I need. I'm getting a numeric value instead of a string. [here's some results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyll.png)
I can join it correctly in SQL, here's my join statement:

```
Select PatientProfile.RaceMId, MedLists.description, MedLists.tablename 
From PatientProfile
left join MedLists on PatientProfile.RaceMId = MedLists.MedListsId;
```

Expected results in SQL

[image: Expected results in SQL]

I'm unsure how to accomplish this in Crystal Reports. I believe my joins are correct and messing around with them didn't change the result. [DB joins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6f0z.png)
I tried writing a formula but syntax is tricky and hasn't produced anything meaningful yet. Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you possibly selecting 'description' from the wrong table? Is the race description not in the PatientProfile table.  Also I am confused on that JOIN because you are joining the RaceMid on MedListsId.  What is the relationship between these 2 fields as hard to tell from the above query. Can you please select top 10 rows from each table and include it in the description? Thanks.

Comment: It would also help if you could provide a description of the results you are getting along with the results you expected.  A description of how your report is setup might be useful as well.  I don't see a problem with the way you are joining the tables in your report.